# Bootstrap 3.0 "row" first item not aligned correctly

Tags: asp.net, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]Using Bootstrap 3.0 and the code below is a snip of a  which contains 3 items, each in a  which looks and works well, except the first element in this row (plus others) is shifted slightly above the other elements within the "ROW." I've attached a screenshot of the issue. I haven't modified the Bootstrap CSS to cause any issues.

Note: the other rows don't contain ASP controls which I thought was the issue but it's not.

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<h2><%: Title %>.</h2>
<hr />
<section id="CreateUserForm">
    <h4>Create User <i class="fa fa-user"></i></h4>
    <!--1st ROW-->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <asp:DropDownList ToolTip="User Role" runat="server" ID="UserRole" CssClass="form-control"        ![enter image description here][2]AppendDataBoundItems="true" DataSourceID="AspNetRoles" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Name" Width="280px">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="-- Select User Role --" Value="" />
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserRole"
                    CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="User Type is required." Display="Dynamic" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="text" runat="server" title="User Name" id="UserName" class="form-control" placeholder="User Name..." />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName"
                    CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="User Name is required." Display="Dynamic" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="text" runat="server" title="First Name" id="FirstName" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name..." />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="FirstName"
                    CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="First Name is required." Display="Dynamic" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--END 1st ROW-->
    <!--2nd Row-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]
The fix was removing "form-group" around the controls and inserting a break after each "ROW"

```
<!--1st ROW-->
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <asp:DropDownList ToolTip="User Role" runat="server" ID="UserRole" CssClass="form-control" AppendDataBoundItems="true" DataSourceID="AspNetRoles" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Name" Width="280px">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="-- Select User Role --" Value="" />
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserRole"
                    CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="User Type is required." Display="Dynamic" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="text" runat="server" title="User Name" id="UserName" class="form-control" placeholder="User Name..." />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName"
                    CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="User Name is required." Display="Dynamic" />
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="text" runat="server" title="First Name" id="FirstName" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name..." />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="FirstName"
                    CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="First Name is required." Display="Dynamic" />
            </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <!--END 1st ROW-->
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap everything in a `.container`.

Comment: The MasterPage contains the wrap container for the content placeholder. It's all wrapped but I will take a look at it.

Comment: Just noticed the picture didn't upload with the original post, I've attached it to give you the result I have.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a form I was creating, I found the answer was to add the column class before the form-group. This fixed the alignment issue and there was no need to add a break between rows (form-group takes care of spacing for you).

```
<!--1st ROW-->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <asp:DropDownList ToolTip="User Role" runat="server" ID="UserRole" CssClass="form-control"        ![enter image description here][2]AppendDataBoundItems="true" DataSourceID="AspNetRoles" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Name" Width="280px">
                <asp:ListItem Text="-- Select User Role --" Value="" />
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserRole"
                CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="User Type is required." Display="Dynamic" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Hope this helps.